# How to write Math formula in Javascript

Tags: javascript, calculation

I have a math formula that I am trying to write as part of a payment calculator but can't figure out how to turn the formula into code (JS). Could someone please help me. Formula below;

-- edit

Apologies for the lack of clarity.

n = - 1/30 x log(1 + b/p (1 - (1 + i)**30**)) / log ( 1 + i )

where

n is the number of months - which is what I am trying to output.
i is the daily rate
b is the balance
p is the monthly payment

--

This is what I had previously;

```
var balance = $('#bal').val();
var interest = $('#apr').val();
var payment = $('#paym').val();
var dayRate = interest/365;
var n = -(1/30) * (Math.log((1 + (balance/payment)) + ((Math.pow(1 - (1 + dayRate), 30))))) / Math.log(1 + dayRate);
```

--

The calculation is to take user input and work out how many months it would take to pay off a credit card. I am just doing this to teach myself some programming - not a real project.

The result of the formula for example - balance 5000, interest rate 12%, and payment 100pm should show the answer of 70 months.

However, as I am getting some very strange results when I output it, clearly my translation of the formula to code is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. Also, are n, b, p, and i variables, right?

Comment: [Math](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)

Comment: Questions like "How can I achieve that." need to include a specific problem or focus and must show that the questioner has already sufficiently dealt with it himself. Stack Overflow is not a site providing programmers doing your job for you or helping you out in this general way.

Comment: `var n= -1/30*Math.log10(1+b/p*(1-(1+i)*30))/Math.log10(1+i)`

Comment: is `i` the imaginary unit?

Answer (score 1):

```
const n = (-1/30) * Math.log10(1 + ((b/p) * (1 - (30 * (i + 1))))) / Math.log10(1 + i);
```

This works. I just transcribed your equation above into valid JS.

`n` will always be `NaN` though unless `p` is negative, is that intentional? If `p` is positive, you are taking the logarithm of a negative number at `Math.log10(1 + ((b/p) * (1 - (30 * (i + 1)))))`.

Comment: Thanks splox. Apologies, im just learning programming - why does it return as NaN? I have tried tweaking the code to; n = (-1/30) * Math.log(1 + ((balance/payment) * (1 - (Math.pow((dayRate + 1), 30))))) / Math.log(1 + dayRate) - but still get NaN as the output. see above for the edited question if that helps. Thanks